# compiling cpp file with clang++

Tags: c++

[This is the code of the main file and the compiler error I get when not using `-std=c++17`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHdsK.jpg)I need to enter this command to compile the file so the program is executable: `clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp address.cpp city.cpp -o main`

If I leave `-std=c++17` out the compiler seems to not recognize declaration with curly brackets anymore.
I'm new to coding and would like to understand why and how to change/fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the problem? Just the "declaration with curly brackets"

Comment: You probably need *at least* `-std=c++11` depending on which exact curly brackets you're talking about and what your clang's default C++ language version is

Comment: `std=c++17`  is compiler flag which tells the compiler which version of C++ to use.

Comment: C++ is a living language. As people run into different problems and find better ways to solve known problems, the language adapts. `-std=c++17` tells the compiler to use the language rules and functionality specified in the 2017 language revision. If you leave this out, the language revision that will be used is defined by the compiler used, and this language revision does not support some of the newer features built into C++17.

Comment: Formally answering this question is hard because there isn't enough information in it to explicitly address the problem you have run into. We can guess, and maybe we'll be right, but guesses leave poor connective tissue between the question and the answer and will likely confuse future askers more than it helps. I recommend editing the question and adding a slimmed down version of your code that demonstrates the problem. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What I found online also gave me the impression that the compiler is using an inferior version of C++. How can I change it, so that it uses C++17 by default? (I added a screenshot of the code to my initial question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.